# Start Spring Boot web application from Linux command line

Tags: java, linux, spring-boot

Using Spring Boot, developed web application and running in Eclipse without any issues. I generated a WAR file using Maven build script. I would like to know, is it possible to start the Spring Boot using WAR file in Linux? If yes, what changes do I need to make. I have used JAR in the past to start the application, not WAR.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to start up spring-boot application via command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47835901/how-to-start-up-spring-boot-application-via-command-line)

Answer (score 2):

`WAR` and `JAR` archive startup is quite different, as you can read in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1842972/11748454).

However, if you use the [build-image](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/#goals) goal of the `spring-boot-maven-plugin` everything gets easier. This plugin creates a hybrid WAR/JAR file, that can be started with:

```
java -jar name_of_the_file.war
```

I tested with the version 2.3 of the plugin, but probably it works with earlier 2.x versions. Basically the plugin creates a wrapper that adds the libraries in `WEB-INF/lib` and `WEB-INF/lib-provided` to your classpath and calls your `@SpringBootApplication` class.